# Implementing CSRF into OpenID iframe

Tags: post, iframe, openid, token, csrf

I've implemented Janrain Open ID on my Codeigniter 2.0 website.  It was working great until I enabled CSRF protection in my codeigniter config file.

I read up on it and it seems that in all my forms on my website I should include a hidden form element containing a token, which is then verified against a cookie token after the post is read from the receiving page.

This is all fine and dandy, but where I'm a bit stuck is when I try to log into my site now using OpenID (of which the login form comes from an iframe that is hosted on janrain.com) I cannot include any sort of hidden post values because I have no control over what the form looks like, and can only supply a return url so that janrain knows what page to return me to.

**How can I get my CSRF token to submit with the form if the form is in an iframe which I don't control?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved.

I ended up sending the iframe my return URL of which I included the CSRF token as part of the URL.  When Janrain returns to my return URL, as Codeigniter goes through the security check inside `Security::csrf_verify()` I do a little check against the URL to see if my tokens match (unfortunately I wasn't able to use CI libraries for some reason so I ended up parsing the URL myself using `explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))`.  If I find a match in the URL to my csrf cookie token then we're all good and I don't check against the POST variables which Codeigniter would normally be doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just add this to the end of your token URL:

```
?ci_csrf_token='.$this->security->get_csrf_hash()
```

So let's say you were using an embeded iframe for Janrain, the complete code would end up looking like this with:

```
<iframe src="https://MYACCOUNT.rpxnow.com/openid/embed?token_url=<?PHP echo rawurlencode($token_url).'?ci_csrf_token='.$this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" seamless="seamless" style="width:400px; height:240px;"></iframe>
```

I have this working great on my codeigniter, and you do not need to disable your CSRF security :)

Answer (score 0):

I also was searching solution how to turn off CSRF per controller. I did it that way:

```
if(stripos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'/controller') === FALSE)
{
    $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
}
else
{
    $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
}
```

in config.php
I don't know if it's reliable,but it works for me.